# What is a "branch" of p-adic exponentiation?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am reading  p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions by Neal Koblitz. Please look at page 27. The definition of $f(x)=n^x$ is unambiguously defined when $n$ is $1 \bmod p$. Next, for any $n$ coprime to $p$, he first fixes an $s_0$ and works with $S_{s_0}$. Later he makes the remarks that the function $f$ depends on $s_{0}$ as well as $n$. I didn't quite understand what he means by dependence on $s_0$? Does he mean if you get $n^x$ via two sets $S_{s_0}$ and $S_{s_1}$ for two numbers $s_0$ and $s_1$, then do we get two distinct $p$-adic numbers? Can I see an example where this happens?

My second but related question is, if $a$ is a $p$-adic integer coprime to $p$, and $s$ is an integer in ${0,1,\ldots,p-2}$ and if $v=s/(p-1) \in \mathbb Z_p$, then do we have $a^s=(a^{p-1})^v$ ? (where $(a^{p-1})^v$ is well defined because $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$. )

If the answer to my second question is positive, I suspect all the $p-2$ "branches" of exponentiation corresponding to each $s_0$ are same.

Third question: Why do this fix an $s_0$ business at all? Why not just do this:
Given any $x \in \mathbb Z_p$, and $n$ coprime to $p$, just write $x$ as limit of sequence of integers $x_m$ such that $x_m \equiv x_{m-1} \bmod p^m(p-1)$ (which can be achieved by induction) and define $n^x$ as the limit of $n^{x_m}$. I suspect this may fail because I haven't checked if the $x_m$ we get are necessarily non-negative.

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The answer to the second question is no, of course not; if $a$ is an ordinary integer then exponentiating $a$ just produces other ordinary integers in the usual way, and it's easy to find a counterexample there.

Answer (score 5):

I think Gouvea's book *$p$-Adic Numbers: An Introduction* explains this idea more clearly in his section titled "Interpolation", and the account below is similar to that.  It shows what happens when the OP's third question "why do this fix an $s_0$ business at all?" is taken seriously, but instead of using exponents in $\mathbf Z_p$ we use exponents in $\mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z_p$.

Fix $a \in \mathbf Z_p^\times$.  Let $\omega(a)$ be the Teichmuller representation of $a$: $\omega(a)^{p-1} = 1$ and $\omega(a) = a\bmod p$. Then set $\langle a \rangle = a/\omega(a)$, so $\langle a \rangle \equiv 1 \bmod p$ and $a = \omega(a)\langle a\rangle$. This decomposition of $a$ is multiplicative: $\omega(ab) = \omega(a)\omega(b)$ and $\langle ab\rangle = \langle a\rangle\langle b\rangle$.  It is the usual multiplative decomposition
$$
\mathbf Z_p^\times = \mu_{p-1} \times (1 + p\mathbf Z_p).
$$
(For $p = 2$, where $\mu_{p-1}$ is trivial, this trivial decomposition is sometimes replaced by the refinement $\mathbf Z_2^\times = \{\pm 1\} \times (1 + 4\mathbf Z_2)$, but I won't use that here. Note all $2$-adic units $a$ are in $1+2\mathbf Z_2$, so there is no subtlety about interpolating ordinary integral powers of $a$ to $2$-adic integer powers of $a$: the sequence $a^n$ is $2$-adically uniformly continuous in $n$ for $n \in \mathbf Z$.)

Because $\langle a\rangle \equiv 1 \bmod p$, the integral powers $\langle a\rangle^n$ for $n \in \mathbf Z$ are $p$-adically uniformly continuous in $n$ and extend by continuity to $p$-adic integer powers $\langle a\rangle^x$ for $x \in \mathbf Z_p$, which restrict to the *usual* integral powers when $x \in \mathbf Z$.

For general $a$ in $\mathbf Z_p^\times$, $a^n$ is not necessarily $p$-adically continuous in $n$. To extend the exponent in $a^n$ $p$-adically, we'll enlarge the exponent domain *not* to $\mathbf Z_p$, but to the product group $\mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z_p$:  define $f \colon \mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf Z_p^\times$ by
$$
f(r,x) = \omega(a)^r\langle a\rangle^x.
$$
Note $\omega(a)^r$ only depends on $r$ modulo $p-1$ because $\omega(a)^{p-1} = 1$. (In fact, $\omega(a)^r$ only depends on $r \bmod d$ where $d$ is the order of $\omega(a)$, which is the same as the order of $a \bmod p$.)

The mapping $f$ is a continuous group homomorphism.  To talk about $f$ on $\mathbf Z$, we need to agree on an embedding of $\mathbf Z$ into $\mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z_p$.
Use the diagonal embedding $\Delta \colon \mathbf Z \to \mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z_p$ where $\Delta(n) = (n \bmod p-1, n)$.
Note $\Delta(\mathbf Z) = \{(n \bmod p-1,n) : n \in \mathbf Z\}$
is *dense* in $\mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z_p$ by the Chinese remainder theorem (for moduli $(p-1)p^k$ where $k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$).  So a continuous function on $\mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z$ is completely determined by its image on the diagonal copy of the integers, $\Delta(\mathbf Z)$.

Using $\Delta$ we can "restrict" (better: pull back)  $f$ to a group homomorphism $\mathbf Z \to \mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z_p$ as the mapping $f \circ \Delta$:
$$
(f \circ \Delta)(n) = f(n \bmod p-1,n) = \omega(a)^n\langle a\rangle^n.
$$
Because $\langle a\rangle^n$ is the usual $n$th power of $\langle a\rangle$ when $n \in \mathbf Z$ and $\langle a\rangle = a/\omega(a)$,
$$
(f \circ \Delta)(n) = \omega(a)^n\langle a\rangle^n = 
\omega(a)^n(a/\omega(a))^n = a^n.
$$
Voila: $f$ restricted to the dense diagonal copy of $\mathbf Z$ inside $\mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z_p$ is the ordinary notion of integral powers of $a$. So $f$ is an interpolation of all the ordinary integral powers $a^n$ to $p$-adic integer powers of $a$, but the the exponent domain for $f$ is not $\mathbf Z_p$: it is $\mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z_p$.

**Example**.  If $a \equiv 1 \bmod p$, so $\omega(a) = 1$ and $\langle a\rangle = a$, we have
$$f(r,x) = \omega(a)^r\langle a\rangle^x = \langle a\rangle^x = a^x.$$ Thus $f$ is independent of its first coordinate and we can just ignore it, obtaining in this way the usual idea of $p$-adic interpolation of exponents with base $a$ when $a \equiv 1 \bmod p$: the mapping $f \colon \mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf Z_p^\times$ collapses to the mapping $\mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf Z_p^\times$ where $x \mapsto a^x$.

What does this have to do with the branch method of interpolation in Koblitz's book?  His $p-1$ different interpolations of $a^n$ are what you get if you *fix* the first coordinate of the mapping $f \colon \mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf Z_p^\times$ in order to create a mapping $\mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf Z_p^\times$: for each $\overline{r} \in \mathbf Z/(p-1)$, set
$f_r \colon \mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf Z_p^\times$ by
$$
f_r(x) = f(r,x) = \omega(a)^r\langle a\rangle^x.
$$
Since $\mathbf Z$ is a (dense) subset of $\mathbf Z_p$, for $n \in \mathbf Z$ we get
$$
f_r(n) = f(r,n) =  \omega(a)^r\langle a\rangle^n.
$$
Since $\langle a\rangle^n$ is the ordinary $n$th power of $\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle a\rangle = a/\omega(a)$,
$$
f_r(n) = \omega(a)^r\langle a\rangle^n = \omega(a)^r(a/\omega(a))^n = 
\omega(a)^{r-n}a^n.
$$
This is usually *not* equal to $a^n$, since it's usually not $f(n,n)$, but it is equal to $a^n$ if $n \equiv r \bmod p-1$:
$$
n \equiv r \bmod p-1 \Longrightarrow \omega(a)^{n-r} = 1 \Longrightarrow f_r(n) = a^n.
$$
More generally, if $n \equiv r \bmod d$ where $d$ is the order of $a \bmod p$, then $f_r(n) = a^n$. (For example, if $a \equiv 1 \bmod p$ so $d = 1$, then $f_r(n) = a^n$ for all $n$ as $\omega(a) = 1$.)
So $f_r(n) = a^n$ when $n \in r + (p-1)\mathbf Z$, which is a dense subset of $\mathbf Z_p$, and is not all of $\mathbf Z$ if $p > 2$.

**Remark**. Since $f_r(x)$ only depends on $r$ through the value of $\omega(a)^r$, we have $f_r = f_{r'}$ if $r \equiv r' \bmod d$ where $d$ is the order of $\omega(a)$ (which is the order of $a \bmod p$). Therefore the number of genuinely different "branch" functions $f_r$ for $r \in \mathbf Z/(p-1)$ is equal to the order of $\omega(a)$. In case $a \equiv 1 \bmod p$, so $\omega(a) = 1$, this recovers what we saw before: all $p-1$ "branches" $f_r$ are the same.

**Example**.
$f_0(x) = \langle a\rangle^x$, so $f_0(n) = \langle a\rangle^n = (a/\omega(a))^n = \omega(a)^{-n}a^n$. This mapping $f_0 \colon \mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf Z_p^\times$ is a group homomorphism, and $f_0(n) = a^n$ if and only if $\omega(a)^n = 1$, which is equivalent to $n$ being divisible by the order of the root of unity $\omega(a)$ (same as the order of $a \bmod p$).

**Example**. Take $a = 5$ and $p = 7$, so
$$
\langle a\rangle = 5/\omega(5) = 1 + 7 + 5\cdot 7^2 + 5\cdot 7^3 + 2\cdot 7^4 + 3\cdot 7^5 +\cdots,
$$
which is in $1+7\mathbf Z_7$. For $r = 0, 1, \ldots, 5 \bmod 6$ we have a mapping $f_r \colon \mathbf Z_7 \to \mathbf Z_7^\times$ where $f_r(x) = \omega(5)^r\langle 5\rangle^x$. Consider $r = 3$:
$$
f_3(1) = \omega(5)^3\langle 5\rangle = \omega(5)^3(5/\omega(5)) = \omega(5)^2 5
$$
and
$$
f_3(2) = \omega(5)^3\langle 5\rangle^2 = \omega(5)^3(5/\omega(5))^2 = \omega(5)5^2.
$$
Thus $f_3(1+1) = \omega(5)5^2 = \omega(5)25$ while $f_3(1)^2 = \omega(5)^425$, so $f_3(1+1) \not= f_3(1)f_3(1)$ because $\omega(5)$ has order $6$.
If $n \equiv 3 \bmod 6$ then $n-3$ is a multiple of $6$, so
$$
f_3(n) = \omega(5)^3\langle 5\rangle^n = \omega(5)^3(5/\omega(5))^n = \omega(5)^{3-n}5^n = 5^n. 
$$

Even though $f \colon \mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf Z_p^\times$ is a continuous group homomorphism,
the $p-1$ continuous mappings $f_r \colon \mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf Z_p^\times$ are usually not group homomorphisms for the same reason that a group homomorphism $G_1 \times G_2 \to G_3$ is usually not a group homomorphism if you fix its first coordinate and view what's left as a function $G_2 \to G_3$. By combining all the continuous mappings $f_r$ for $0 \leq r \leq p-2$ into a *single* function $f \colon \mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf Z_p^\times$ on a product group where $f(r,x) = f_r(x) = \omega(a)^r\langle a\rangle^x$, we get a continuous group homomorphism that looks like a genuine interpolation of *all* integral powers $a^n$ provided we view $\mathbf Z$ as a dense subset of that product group via the diagonal embedding. Koblitz only discusses the individual functions $f_r$ on $\mathbf Z_p$, which each appear to have less convenient features overall as an "interpolation" of the integer powers $a^n$ than the combination of all $f_r$ as a single function $f$ on the product group $\mathbf Z/(p-1) \times \mathbf Z_p$.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a little old, but I ran across it while trying to figure out the answer to "why doesn't this example I have work?" So for others who come looking, here's a good example of what Koblitz describes.

Consider $5\in\mathbb{Q}_{11}$. If I want to find $\sqrt[3]{5} \in \mathbb{Q}_{11}$, I can do so using Hensel's Lemma/Lifting on $r^3-5=0$ and get
$$r=\sqrt[3]{5} = \dots649393242043_{11}$$
when represented as an infinite-digit base-11 number.

Instead I might try to compute $\sqrt[3]{5}=5^{1/3}$, i.e. compute $f(s)=5^s$ at $s=1/3$. As an element of $\mathbb{Q}_{11}$, $$1/3 = ...7373737374_{11}.$$
But computing $f(s)$ on the sequence $$4_{11}, 74_{11}, 374_{11}, 7374_{11}, 37374_{11}, \dots$$ does not converge in $\mathbb{Q}_{11}$. (Note: It does cluster around two values: $r'=\dots 438785419_{11}$ and $r''=\dots24852a55_{11}$ because the repeating digit block of $1/3$ is length two and the sum of those two digits is divisible by 10. But notice neither of these is $r$.)

However, if I keep in mind what Koblitz says about requiring a sequence that is a subset of $S_{s_0}$, particularly $S_7$, then the sequence $$x_i: 34_{11}, 674_{11}, 3374_{11}, 67374_{11}, 337374_{11}, \dots$$ has $x_i \equiv 7 \mod 10$ for all $i$ and $x_i \to 1/3$ and $5^{x_i} \to r$ in $\mathbb{Q}_{11}$.

For completeness, here's where the other branches converge to:
$$x_i \in S_0 \text{ or }S_5 \text{ gives } 5^{x_i} \to \dots71708669351_{11}$$
$$x_i \in S_1 \text{ or }S_6 \text{ gives } 5^{x_i} \to \dots00524852a55_{11}=r''$$
$$x_i \in S_2 \text{ or }S_7 \text{ gives } 5^{x_i} \to \dots49393242043_{11} = r$$
$$x_i \in S_3 \text{ or }S_8 \text{ gives } 5^{x_i} \to \dots22157782354_{11}$$
$$x_i \in S_4 \text{ or }S_9 \text{ gives } 5^{x_i} \to \dots78438785419_{11}=r'$$

How should we think about the other non-$r$ limits? I don't know...

Comment: Divide, let us say, $r'$ by $r$. The result is a fifth root of unity. If you now multiply any cube root of $5$ successively by this fifth root of unity you cycle through all five branches. The existence of $r$ and $r'$ alone forces all five branches to come into view. Oh ... you picked a radicand that isn't a primitive root $\bmod 11$. You may want to see what happens with the cube root of something that is primitive, like $2$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thank you! This answers the question I had originally ("what are these other limit points?") when I stumbled across this post.

Comment: Check out my development with this example.

Answer (score 2):

This answer expands upon Aeryk's.

Out of the five branch values for the cube root of $5$ in $11$-adics, only the one ending with $...043$ actually solves $r^3=5$. The others solve equations of the form $r^3=5\omega^k$ where $\omega$ is any one of the other four, primitive fifth roots of unity and $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. The branches then correspond to $...043\omega^{2k}$ where $(\omega^2)^3=\omega$.

We can generate all the branches without any direct computation of subsequences. To do so, first solve the nominal cubic equation $r^3=5$ with Hensel lifting, getting $...043$.

Second, determine a root via the exponential/logarithm method, to wit, render

$5^{1/3}=\exp[(\ln5)/3].$

We might try obtain the logarithm by plugging in $x=4$ to the Maclaurin series for $\ln(1+x)$, but of course $|4|\not<1$ in the $11$-adic norm so the series diverges. To get around this problem we raise $5$ to a power that has residue $1\bmod11$, and adjust the coefficient of the logarithm accordingly. We find that $5^5=2391$ (all arithmetic is done in base $11$) suffices, so we render

$5^{1/3}=5^{5/14}=\exp[\ln(2391)/14].$

Then the Maclaurin series gives

$\ln2391=...190.$

Dividing by $14$ then gives $...750$ whose exponential via the Maclaurin series for $\exp(x)$ is $...351$.

We thus have the two branch values $...043$ and $...351$, and we may divide the former by the latter to generate $...103$, which works out to a fifth root of unity to the digits shown in $11$-adics.

We then have all the branches defined by the subsequence limits of Aeryk:

$...351×...103=...043$

$...043×...103=...419$

$...419×...103=...A55$

$...A55×...103=...354$

$...354×...103=...351$

As a final note, $5$ is not a primitive root $\bmod 11$. Rather it is the square of a primitive root, so the multipliers that connect the branches are fifth roots of unity rather than tenth roots and we get just the five branches given in these two answers. Had we chosen a primitive root, such as $2$, for our cube-root radicand, we would have gotten a tenth-root multiplier and generated ten branches -- one for each $\bmod 10$ residue of the subsequences.